# how to use passport.js in a proper way

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying passport library to authenticate api request. To start I have created a NodeJS application with the express framework. The project contains some apis that serve some data. In public folder it contains index.html page having username and password field.

**Index.html**

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Created a **server.ts** that create a http server and listen on some port and created apis using express framework.

**Server.ts**

```
let userList: User[] = [new User(1, "Sunil"), new User(2, "Sukhi")];

let app = express();

// passport library
let passport = require('passport');
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// middlewares
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({ resave: false, saveUninitialized: true, secret: "secretKey123!!" }));

// passport middleware invoked on every request to ensure session contains passport.user object
app.use(passport.initialize());
// load seriliazed session user object to req.user 
app.use(passport.session());

// Only during the authentication to specify what user information should be stored in the session.
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log("Serializer : ", user)
    done(null, user.userId);
});

// Invoked on every request by passport.session
passport.deserializeUser(function (userId, done) {
        let user = userList.filter(user => userId === user.userId);
        console.log("D-serializer : ", user);
        // only pass if user exist in the session
        if (user.length) {
            done(null, user[0]);
        }
});
// passport strategy : Only invoked on the route which uses the passport.authenticate middleware.
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'name',
    passwordField: 'password'
},
    function (username, password, done) {
        console.log("Strategy : Authenticating if user is valid  :", username)
        let user = userList.filter(user => username === user.userName)
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }
));

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/done',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

app.get('/done', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Done")
    res.send("done")
})

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    console.log("login")
    res.send("login")
})

// http server creation
let server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log('Up and running on port 7000');
});
```

Now when I hit **localhost:7000** it opens the login page and when I click submit with username from `userList` it returns the done otherwise login. This is fine.

Now every call goes through `deserializeUser` method.

The problem is when I call other URLs directly without hitting /login (authenticates the user) they also work fine and return data.

I was expecting that if the request is not authenticated all other calls will fail as `deserializeUser` is intercepting every request but in this case, no passport method is called.

Is this how it works? or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing middleware to authenticate all subsequent requests. So I have created `isAuthenticated` method (thanks @Sombrero).

```
// request interceptor that will check user authentication
private static isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Authenticating :", req.originalUrl)
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
};
```

and then in every request

```
app.get('/done', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.send("done")
});
```

but this was tough to use `isAuthenticated` method in every request. So I created an array of API list that is public and added middleware to intercept every request and updated `isAuthenticated` method to ignore public apis

```
// list of apis for which authentication is not required
private static publicApiList: string[] = ["/login"];

// request interceptor that will check user authentication
private static isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Authenticating :", req.originalUrl)
    if (req.isAuthenticated() || Server.publicApiList.indexOf(req.originalUrl) > -1) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
};
```

and then used this method as middleware

```
app.use(Server.isAuthenticated)
```

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but one problem that you might face with this strategy is that if you're designing a Restful API and decided to do the following: 

GET /posts (a public endpoint that returns posts) and 

POST /posts (a private endpoint for creating posts).

If you use the function proposed above, you won't be able to differentiate between the routes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a middleware, for check if your user is authenticated:

```
isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      //if user is logged in, req.isAuthenticated() will return true 
      return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
};
```

And you have to use that middleware like that:

```
//if user not authenticated, he will be redirect on /login
app.get('/done', isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.send("done")
});
```

Comment: dont you think this should be automatic.I mean i should not put any middleware for all request

Comment: No it's not automatic, like that you can choose which routes are public and which routes where the user need to be logged in for access it